# Regex to capture most of alternating pattern

Tags: regex

I have the following file names which should pass through regex

```
6505208533_95d2834be5_b@2x.jpg
6505208533_95d2834be5_b~ipad.jpg
6505208533_95d2834be5_b~ipad@2x.jpg
6505218557_8407260688_b@2x.png
6505218557_8407260688_b~ipad.png
6505218557_8407260688_b~ipad@2x.png
6505237749_b71c648be2_b@2x.jpg
6505237749_b71c648be2_b~ipad.jpg
6505237749_b71c648be2_b~ipad@2x.jpg
```

The following regex should capture all file name suffixes: ~ipad@2x, @2x and ~ipad.

```
(.+)(@2x|~ipad|~ipad@2x)\.(?:jpg|png)
```

However, it does NOT capture `~ipad@2x`. How to solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the lazy operator after `.+`:

```
(.+?)
```

instead of:

```
(.+)
```

Otherwise it will try to be greedy and match the longest possible string ([demo](http://regex101.com/r/qU1uY5/1)).

Answer (score 0):

The better and more semantically correct solution is to simply change the order of your suffixes since your combo suffix "~ipad@2x" is never reached in the search because it is a combination of the other two which always match first:

```
(.+?)(~ipad@2x|@2x|~ipad)\.(?:jpg|png)
```